Interpretation of estimated effect of a predictor variable when it does not vary within a sampling unit
Let us consider the following scenario. John is soon going to quiz his students and he is interested to know if the font type with which a quiz is formatted is associated with the performance of the students on the quiz. John hypothesizes that the students who scored higher on the last two quizzes would also score high on the upcoming quizzes. John calculates the average score from the last two quizzes and names it last_score. The upcoming quizzes are similar in various aspects to the last two quizzes: each upcoming quiz would also have 10 questions, with each correct response contributing a score of 1 to the total score of the quiz. John uses an ordered variable new_score to log the total score from each of the upcoming quizzes. The two font types John would use on the quiz would be Arial and Times New Roman; John codes them with a factor variable type.
He sets up two random-intercepts models to model the conditional multinomial distribution of new_score as a function of last_score and type with proportional odds structure:
formula.mod1 <- new_score ~ last_score + type + (1 | student)

formula.mod2 <- new_score ~ last_score*type + (1 | student)

While formatting one of the six quizzes John will administer in order to test the effect of font type on quiz performance, John asks himself, “How should I interpret the coefficient of last_score of the random-intercepts model with formula formula.mod1”? John believes the quizzes do not vary much in terms of difficulty. He uses two sequences, ‘ATATAT’ and ‘TATATA’ where T represents the font ‘Times New Roman’ and A represents ‘Arial’, to make sure each student gets to solve both types of quizzes, ranks students using last_score and assigns each sequence alternatively to the ranked list of students.
Given that last_score does not change across six quizzes assessed for a student, would it be okay to model new_score with a random-intercepts model with the random-intercepts following a MVN distribution (such as models fitted with ordinal::clmm)? If yes, how does one interpret the estimated effect of last_score on new_score for a given participant?

Do you really want to know how the odds of moving up one unit on new_score relate to last_score and type, or do you simply want to get a sense of their linear relationships? Ten categories is a lot, and it begs the question why you wouldn't go with a simpler linear mixed effects model.

Sorry, another question. To clarify, last_score will be an average, so it is a student level variable, where type is a trial level variable, yes? If so, then it is the nature of a higher level variable that it wouldn't vary within a higher-level unit. It's a characteristic of that unit, in this case, the student's "ability" as indexed by prior performance

@RickHass (1) I don't have strong reasons to prefer odds over linear relationship, but I feel validating a model would be less tricky if we use a discrete distribution, right? I can't really get to simulating a data set right away, but it would be interesting to see how the estimates of an LMM differ from a CLMM (specified by ordinal::clmm).

(2) Yes, last_score is a student-level variable, and type is a trial-level variable. I wanted to know if the model specification makes sense if we are restricted to models where subject-specific estimates are different than their population-level counterparts.

Let's first examine a simple glmm treating new_score as numeric.
As you have described it, you have two models, in Raudenbush & Bryk notation:
Model 1: Random intercept, no interaction
Level 1 (person-task):
$$
Y_{ti} = \pi_{0i} + \pi_{1i}\times \text{Arial}_{ti} + e_{ti}
$$
level 2 (person):
$$
\pi_{0i} = \beta_{00} + \beta_{01} \times \text{Last Score}_{1i} + r_{0i} \\
\pi_{1i} = \beta_{10}
$$
Combined:
$$
Y_{ti} = \beta_{00} + \beta_{01} \times \text{Last Score}_{1i} + \beta_{10}\times \text{Arial}_{ti} +  r_{0i} + e_{ti}
$$
Interpretation
$\beta_{01}$ is the effect of last score on participants' mean new score's (averaged across participants) on Times New Roman tasks, but you're not allowing that effect to vary by font type.
Model 2: Random intercept, with interaction
Level 1 (person-task):
$$
Y_{ti} = \pi_{0i} + \pi_{1i}\times \text{Arial}_{ti} + e_{ti}
$$
level 2 (person):
$$
\pi_{0i} = \beta_{00} + \beta_{01} \times \text{Last Score}_{1i} + r_{0i} \\
\pi_{1i} = \beta_{10} + \beta_{11} \times \text{Last Score}_{1i}
$$
Combined:
$$
Y_{ti} = \beta_{00} + \beta_{01} \times \text{Last Score}_{1i} + r_{0i} + \{ \beta_{10} + \beta_{11} \times \text{Last Score}_{1i} + r_{1i} \}\times \text{Arial}_{ti} + e_{ti} \\
= \beta_{00} + \beta_{01} \times \text{Last Score}_{1i} + \beta_{10} \times \text{Arial}_{ti} + \beta_{11} \times \{\text{Last Score}_{1i} \times \text{Arial}_{ti} \} + r_{0i} + e_{ti}
$$
Interpretation
$\beta_{01}$ is the effect of last score on the mean new score on Times New Roman tasks, but you are allowing that effect to vary by font type, and $\beta_{01}$ will tell you if there is a different level of relationship between last score and new score by task type.
Changing to the cumulative logit model, with proportional odds, using a generalized linear model specification, we change $Y_{ti}$ to the linear predictor $\eta_{ti}$ and from Bauer and Sterba we have the following model (moving the error term and thus changing the level 1 residuals) and link function:
Model
$$
\eta_{ti} =  \beta_{00} + \beta_{01} \times \text{Last Score}_{1i} + \beta_{10}\times \text{Arial}_{ti} +  r_{0i}\\
Y_{ti}^{(c)} = g^{-1}[\nu^{(c)} - \eta_{ti}] + e_{ij}
$$
Inverse Link (logistic)
$$
g^{-1}[\nu^{(c)} - \eta_{ti}] = \frac{\exp(\nu^{(c)} - \eta_{ti})}{1+\exp(\nu^{(c)} - \eta_{ti})}
$$
Interpretation
With the assumption of proportional odds, you have one set of $\beta$'s and $c-1$ thresholds for $c$ categories. The interpretation of $\beta_{01}$ is similar to above, but now, it represents the change in log-odds of being at or below a particular category on the outcome. Depending upon how you code your variable, you can flip this, so that it is more similar to ordinary logistic regression.
The coefficients can be exponentiated to be odds-ratios, but when you do that, it slightly complicates the interpretation similar to multilevel logistic regression, i.e., it is no longer a weighted average effect.
Finally, the level-2 random effects remain multivariate normal. Only the level-1 residuals change in distribution.


Given that last_score does not change across six quizzes assessed for a student, would it be okay to model new_score with a random-intercepts model with the random-intercepts following a MVN distribution (such as models fitted with ordinal::clmm)?

Yes. Having a random intercept grouped by student does not conflict including a predictor that stays the same within each student across different measurements. However, your model specification misses important fixed effects of the quiz number as a categorical predictor to control for quiz difficulties, even if they can be nonsignificant. You can also add random slopes of last_score, type, quiz and let them possibly correlate, but it might be too complex a model that fitting procedure will fail.
clmm(new_score ~ last_score * type * quiz + (1 | student))
clmm(new_score ~ last_score * type * quiz + (1 + last_score * type * quiz | student))


If yes, how does one interpret the estimated effect of last_score on new_score for a given participant?

The coefficients are on the log odds scale if using the default link = "logit" in clmm(), which is difficult to interpret. We can say that a positive is associated with a higher probability of the top level of the response, but the impact on probabilities of other levels of the response is ambiguous. You can try the R package marginaleffects::avg_comparisons() to calculate the marginal effects on the probabilities, which is much easier to interpret. Note that such impacts vary depending on the value of all predictors. That is, the impact of increasing one unit of last_score on the probability of each level of new_score depends on type and quiz even if you do not have any interaction terms in the model.
In mixed models, the coefficient estimates are conditional on the random terms. We can interpret them as "Within the same student, ..." I am not sure how random terms are controlled for in marginaleffects::avg_comparisons() calculations, but you can find out at https://marginaleffects.com/chapters/mrp.html. Some fitting routine allows both existing and new random group levels in the predict() method, which affect the calculation of uncertainty measures like standard errors and confidence intervals. I think that in the former case, the random term is fixed at its best linear unbiased prediction (BLUP) of the given group and does not go into uncertainty measures, whereas in the latter case, the random term is expressed as a random variance and goes into uncertainty measures.

It seemed like the OP didn't care about the ordering of the tests, just what type they were. This would be consistent with a repeated measures experiment, where order could be randomized.

If that is the case, quiz should represent the question book version.
